# Permanently store scanner input into a string

Tags: java, string

I'm looking to make a savable program in java. Lets say i have a scanner "s", and a string "str". Is there any way that i can take input from "s" and store it in "str" permanently? By this is mean normally once the program is exited, the data that was temporarily stored in "str" would be lost. I'm trying to find a way to keep this data stored in str forever (or until other input is given). I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a straight, relevant answer. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write the data in `str` to a file when the program exits, then read it out of that file when the program starts. Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) on basic I/O in Java.